# Laravel 5.2: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails, without using a laravelcollective

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a simple Group Model and a Contact Model.

Contact "belongsTo" a Group and a Group "hasMany" Contact.

Therefore my article migration has a foreign key called "user_id".

```
*Group.php*
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Group extends Model
{
    public function contacts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Contact', 'group_id');
    }
}
```

*Contact.php*

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Contact extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'company', 'email', 'phone', 'address', 'group_id'];

    public function group()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Group', 'group_id');
    }
}

*ContactsController.php*
public function create()
{
    // return 'Create New Contact';
    $groups = Group::all();

    return view('contacts.create', ['groups' => $groups]);

}
```

Comment: Therefore my article migration has a foreign key called "group_id" * Sorry for error!

Comment: empty your db table that has foreign key and then run migration

Comment: When run migration spells "[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
  Class 'CreateGroupsTable' not found"

Comment: `
   public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('contacts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('group_id')->unsigned()->default(0);
            $table->foreign('group_id')->references('id')->on('groups')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('name');            
            $table->string('company');            
            $table->string('email');            
            $table->string('phone');            
            $table->string('address');       
            $table->timestamps();
        });

`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Remove all tables from your database
2. Run `composer dump-autoload`
3. Check that all your migration files have the correct file names, class names and date prefixes **(see below)**
4. Run `php artisan migrate`

Migrations:

**Class name must be in accordance with filename**

For example: in file "2014_12_08_100923_create_items_tables.php" must be class with name "CreateItemsTables" with using CamelCase words.

**File name must follow correct date prefix format**

The migration files must be named as follows YYYY_MM_DD_000000_create_some_table.php

Comment: I've completed the steps and found an error in the name of one of the tables, but it gives me the same mistake when entering a new contact. I use dummy data for Datebase Seeder.php.In ContactsControlle ->public function create()
    {
        // return 'Create New Contact';
        $groups = Group::all();

        return view('contacts.create', ['groups' => $groups]);
        
    }